# Proper way to create a reusable jQuery Object

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to code my first non-hacked up jQuery plug-in and I'm struggling to create a basic object with a constructor, public variables, private variables, and functions.

http://jqueryboilerplate.com/ has a great guide for creating objects that extend jQuery, but I don't think this is the right way to go for a generic object not attached to a DOM element.

Does anyone have a boilerplate template for creating a basic reusable object?  i.e.

```
var calc = new CustomCalculator({'starting_value': 42});
calc.add(3);
calc.multiplyBy(2);
alert(calc.total);   // Alerts (42 + 3) * 2 = 90
```

Comment: Don't really see how your example code has anything to do with jQuery.

Comment: jQuery Boilerplate is quite nice actually. It handle private variables and extend jQuery the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code sample it seems you just need a basic way of creating a JS object.
This would do the trick (but there are lots of other ways to do it):

```
function CustomCalculator(options){
    var self = this;
    self.total = options.starting_value;

    self.add = function(term){
        self.total += term;
    };

    self.multiplyBy = function(term){
        self.total = self.total * term;
    };
}

var calc = new CustomCalculator({'starting_value': 42});
calc.add(3);
calc.multiplyBy(2);
alert(calc.total);   // Alerts 90
```

You'd still have to implement the string concatenation, but I'll leave that up to you

If you want private variables you should use closures.
I recently wrote an article about namespaces and modules in JavaScript which could help you: http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/04/27/javascript-namespaces-and-modules/

And here's another one specifically about private variables: http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2012/04/22/private-variables-in-javascript/

Comment: That's perfect Kenneth.  I'll read over your articles as well.  Thanks a ton!  BTW - I don't yet get the importance of hiding private variables, aside from clarity.  I guess I should Google that.  :)